# UITableView editable (rearrangeable) without cells beeing deletable

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I was wondering if there is a way to make a UITableView editable in a way where the user is able to rearrange (move) individual TableViewCells, BUT without the "Remove-Cell"-Feature to appear.

thank you for your help

sam

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Have you tried implementing the editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath method and returning UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone?

Comment: Perfect Solution!

Answer (score 0):

You change the **if condition** based on  your requirement

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
      // in below if your write your condition on which delete is enable or disable
 if ([[friednListArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row][@"id"] isEqualToString:user.userId]) {
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
}
 else{
     return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
     }
}
```