# How do I not allow delete functionality in a UITableView?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am using a UITableView and when I setEditing:YES I don't want a delete option to be available.  I just want the ability to reorder the rows of the table.  Is there a way to prevent the - button from showing up on the left?

Comment: possible duplicate of [UITableView editable (rearrangeable) without cells beeing deletable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281394/uitableview-editable-rearrangeable-without-cells-beeing-deletable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this:
[UITableView editable (rearrangeable) without cells beeing deletable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281394/uitableview-editable-rearrangeable-without-cells-beeing-deletable/2281456#2281456)