# How do I disable the delete operation for certain row in a UITableView?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I know about using `setEditing:` to enable the editing mode of UITableView.

But I prefer to disable the operation for some certain rows (enable other rows).

Is it possible?

Thanks,

interdev

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Implement [the `-tableView:canEditRowAtIndexPath:` method](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006941-CH3-SW26) in your data source. Return `NO` for those rows.

Comment: Thanks. But I hope the certain rows(all rows can be moved) can be moved rather than delete (certain rows are disabled the delete function, the others are enabled), Is it possible?

Comment: @user: Use `-tableView:canMoveRowAtIndexPath:` for moving.

Comment: Thanks. I used
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableview canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  
     return YES;
  
}
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
 NSInteger row=[indexPath row];
 int vv=[[myArray objectAtIndex:row]  isEditable];
 if (!vv)
 {
     return NO;
 }
 else
 {
  return YES;  
 }
}
but it looks like impossible to set a cell 'enable move' and 'disable delete' at the same time.

Comment: @user: Have you set the cell's [`.showsReorderControl` property](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006938-CH3-SW15) to YES?

Comment: Bit late to the party with this one, but I don't think this is what the OP was after. This still doesn't allow the user to move rows but not edit. @OP: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281394/uitableview-editable-rearrangeable-without-cells-beeing-deletable/2281456#2281456

Comment: [`tableView(_:canEditRowAt:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasource/1614900-tableview)

Answer (score 10):

this post sum it up perfectly, 
[Is there any way to hide "-" (Delete) button while editing UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020922/is-there-any-way-to-hide-delete-button-while-editing-uitableview)

in case you don't want to read the post the gist is on the row you don't want to delete but want to allow move row: set edit style for row to UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone; 
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Using canEditRowAtIndexPath will not allow the row to align with other cells in grouped style. which can look bad.

I use `UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone`, for the rows which you do not want to show the edit control (minus/plus button), put this in your

```
(UITableViewCellEditingStyle) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{}
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on your question, I understand that you want to just hide the delete button from appearing on the 1st row. please set tableview editing to yes and add the below code

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if(indexPath.row==0)
    {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: This works but will also disable moving rows. If cell movement is to be allowed along with disabling delete button solution suggested by @Youyou and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281394/uitableview-editable-rearrangeable-without-cells-beeing-deletable/2281456#2281456 by AlexC is the better option to go for.