# Reordering controls on UITableView while not in editing mode?

Tags: iphone, ios4, uitableview

I have a UITableView and I want to be able to reorder the rows when I'm not in edit mode, meaning I don't want to see the delete icons until I press Edit. I want to be able to see and use the reordering controls all the time. Is that possible?

Do I have to keep the UITableView in editing mode all the time and enable/disable the delete icon manually? How to disable the swipe to delete in that case?

Comment: Set UITableViewCellEditingStyle flag to each cell and implement canMoveRowAtIndexPath and canEditRowAtIndexPath UITableViewDataSource delegate methods. Not sure if you have to be in edit mode permanently to do this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I'm aware you can't do it using just the editing flag. However, it's not hard to achieve a similar effect.

Have your own boolean ie `deleting`. Set the tableview cell to `cell.showsReorderControl = YES`.
Then implement all the methods required for moving cells. The bit of code I think you're looking for is.
`– tableView:editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:` 
if `deleting == YES` return `UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete` otherwise return `UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone`.
Finally, set `tableView.editing = YES` always. If before and after changing the `deleting` bool you run `[tableView beginUpdates]` and `[tableView endUpdates]` everything should work fine. Let me know if this doesn't make sense, and I'll try again.

Comment: by the way this will stop swipe to delete.

Comment: I did like this. Worked nicely. I'm not using the swipe to delete on this, though.

Comment: i have tried but still i need to implement :

**tableview.editing=YES;**

and it shows the red button for deleting..
I wish to just re-order the cells without any editing feature ... can u provide some sample code to : abhishekbedi1432@yahoo.com

Comment: @AbhishekBedi make sure you're implementing `tableView:editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath` and always returning `UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone`.

Comment: @mackross I have a similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21902483/reordering-rows-in-tableview-while-not-in-editing-mode , but I am not able to implement your answer. Would you mind helping me?

Answer (score 19):

I found a solution. `UITableViewCell` refuses to draw the reorder control unless it's in editing mode. Fortunately, `UITableViewCell` and `UITableView` track editing separately, and crucially, `UITableView` actually handles reordering regardless of its own editing mode. We just need to trick the cells into drawing the reorder controls and we're home free.

Subclass `UITableViewCell` like this:

```
class ReorderTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    override var showsReorderControl: Bool {
        get {
            return true // short-circuit to on
        }
        set { }
    }

    override func setEditing(editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        if editing == false {
            return // ignore any attempts to turn it off
        }

        super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)
    }

}
```

Now simply set `editing = true` on cells for which you want to enable reordering. You can make it conditional on `-tableView:canMoveRowAtIndexPath:`.

In your table view data source:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    // Configure the cell...
   :

    cell.editing = self.tableView(tableView, canMoveRowAtIndexPath: indexPath) // conditionally enable reordering

    return cell
}
```

The only drawback is that this is incompatible with the table view `allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing` option; the edit control is incorrectly always shown. A workaround is to enable multiple selection only during actual table view editing.

In your table view controller:

```
override func setEditing(editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)

    self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = editing // enable only during actual editing to avoid cosmetic problem
}
```

Also, in `-viewDidLoad` or your storyboard, set the initial value of `allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing` to false.

Comment: Genius. Been through 10+ SO solutions for this and this is the only that works. Will need to keep an eye on this with future iOS releases, but works fine on iOS 10.1

Comment: Gorgeous, simple solution. `cell.editing` is now `cell.isEditing` in `cellForRow` as of Swift 4.1.

Comment: +1 for research. Unfortunately I hit two problems immediately. Other sections with disclosure indicators (chevrons) became misaligned, as if there's some adverse interference with layout. You also loose animation going in/out of edit mode. It's the usual argument that such delightful hackery will always risk unintended consequences and you have to ask if it's worth the trade in production robustness.  (iOS 11)

Comment: This no longer works in iOS 13. Tested on Beta 1 and Beta 2

Comment: Is there a fix for iOS 13?

Answer (score 10):

Reorder without deletion and no indentation.

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}

- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone; 
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableview shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return NO;
}


- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableview canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}
```

**Reference: Solution posted by Stefan von Chossy [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020922/is-there-any-way-to-hide-delete-button-while-editing-uitableview)**

Comment: Also need to implement `moveRowAt:to:` otherwise the reordering controls are not shown.

Answer (score 1):

Finally can show **Reorder Control** with **Swipe-To-Delete** in **Non-Edit-Mode** for row managed by Core Data NSFetchedResultsController in **Swift 4.1** on **Xcode 9.3** like this:

```
class MyTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    override func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)

        setupAccessoryView()
    }

    func setupAccessoryView() {
        if accessoryView == nil {
            if let reorderCtrl = subviews.first(where: { (subView) -> Bool in
                subView.description.contains("Reorder")
            }) {
                accessoryView = reorderCtrl
            }
        }
    }
}

class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

    var frc: NSFetchedResultsController<MyRow>!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        do {
            // Setup the NSFetchedResultsController here
            try frc.performFetch()

            setEditing(true, animated: false) // Enable for cell reorder control creation on first load
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        setEditing(false, animated: false)
    }

    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)

        setEditing(true, animated: false) // Enable for cell reorder control creation when managed object is updated or inserted on other view
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        // your data source update here for swipe to delete
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
        // your data source update here for sort property value change
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this works with actual editing controls on top, but for just showing reordering controls all the time, this seems to be working best:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    showsReorderControl = true
    super.layoutSubviews()
}
```