# Reordering rows in tableView while not in editing mode

Tags: ios, uitableview, reorderlist

In my app I have implemented the option to re-order rows, but I am using the default edit button to show the delete button and the three lines icon to move the row.
But I have seen an iOS app that allows the user to move rows directly, without need to enter the edit mode.
I would appreciate any advice to implement that way to allow re-ordering rows directly, not using the edit mode.
Thank you.

Comment: As per my answer in the other question you fake non-editing mode by changing the editing style of each cell to none and then when the user is 'editing' you set the style back to delete. You need to track the users 'editing' mode yourself as your tableview will always be in editing mode.

Comment: @mackross, thank you, but would you mind putting in an answer what should I really do? I mean, cell.showsReorderControl = YES; on cellForRowAtIndexPath, but what other methods are involved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement both

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
```

and have your table view `editing` set to `YES` in order for the reorder controls to show.

Answer (score 3):

use `moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath`: UITableView method

UITableView implements below method.Use it to move rows, or chain them to have some animation of row by row.

```
- (void)moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
```

read in detail about it in **Apple documentation**.

Answer (score 1):

Try to load this from end of your `-viewDidLoad:`

```
self.editing = NO;
[self editTable:nil];
```

`editTable`: is method action of edit button.