# Reorder table view cell without the delete button and implement swipe to delete for rows

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, editing

I read about table view and it's editing styles but I have some problems as there is only three editing style as follow:

1. `UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone`
2. `UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete`
3. `UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert`

I want to have reordering the tableview cells which I implemented successfully using it's delegates.

```
-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{ 
    return YES;
}

-(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
   return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
}
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
   //handle the editing style
}
-(NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toProposedIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)proposedDestinationIndexPath{
  //move cells
}
-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return YES;
}
```

I don't want to use `UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete` as it shows a red circular button on table view. Instead of this I want swipe-to-delete and the reordering functionality together.

Is there any way to implement this?

Comment: Have you done this. I need to do the same

Comment: @ParulGarg sorry for late reply. Yes, please check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31802088/reorder-tableview-cell-with-a-custom-button

Comment: FYI a smart cookie figured a work around to this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6097464/reordering-controls-on-uitableview-while-not-in-editing-mode/33182901#33182901

Answer (score 1):

This can be done but with the following conditions. The swipe-to-delete will only work while the table view is *not* in edit mode and the table re-ording will only work while the table view *is* in edit mode. You will not be able to have swipe-to-delete work at the same time as table re-ordering.

To make this work you need the following:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { 
    return YES;
}

- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   // Only allow deletion when the table isn't being edited
   return tableView.isEditing ? UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone : UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   // handle the row deletion
}

- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toProposedIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)proposedDestinationIndexPath {
    // Check if move is valid
    return proposedDestinationIndexPath;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView * nonnull)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath * nonnull)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath * nonnull)toIndexPath {
    // process the moved row
}
```

You will need the standard Edit button in the navigation bar (or some other way to toggle the table's edit mode). A common way to do this is to add the following line inside your table view controller's `viewDidLoad` method:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [self editButtonItem];
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but iTunes have this functionality so I guess it should be available for us as well.

Comment: iTunes is on your Mac, not your iOS device. Please clarify what you mean.

Comment: I mean apple Music on iOS 8.4 has this ability

Comment: Which screen in the Music app?

Comment: When you play a song and in the player you click on the button to go and see the queue

Comment: Dear toady, I managed to do something like that by using the code on this link: https://github.com/adamraudonis/UITableViewCell-Swipe-for-Options.  But now I have the problem of positioning the reorder button in the correct place like Apple Music

Comment: As @Tys mentioned above, there's an answer that allows you to have swipe-to-delete and reordering without changing modes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6097464/reordering-controls-on-uitableview-while-not-in-editing-mode