# Swipe to delete while editing in UITableView

Tags: swift, uitableview

There used to be a way to have a tableview in edit mode that allows cell swipe to delete.
I want to have the swipe to delete while still showing the reorder control view, and before iOS 13, you just had to override `showsReorderControl` and `setEditing` so that they always return true. It would then allow you to have the reorder control view shown.

[You can find this code here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33182901/7761589)

On iOS 13 this trick doesn't show the control anymore. Does anyone know a way of achieving this ? Or a fix for the above code ?

Thanks to all of you

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Unfortunately not, i ended up adding a way to select the rows with a button to delete them all at once