# How can I hide the three-line 'move' symbol on the right of a UITableViewCell in edit mode?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` with edit mode enabled in my `-viewDidLoad` method. My problem is that I don't need the three-line 'move' symbol on the right of each cell.

```
 [tableview setEditing:YES];
 tableview.allowsSelectionDuringEditing=YES;
```

I need to either have a transparent disclosure button, or hide the disclosure button altogether. I have tried:

```
 cell.editingAccessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
```

But this has no effect. Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Instead of asking a new question, why not try to look at this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020922/is-there-any-way-to-hide-delete-button-while-editing-uitableview

Comment: Before asking new questions, search weather the question is already asked or not.

Comment: @R.A that all are i am tried.i am asking about the draging of cell disclosureindicator of three lines in the right part of the cell.

Comment: @hacker, Sorry, I am not able understand what u r asking for. Can u post a screen shot and mark what u don't want?. perhaps that should explain your need.

Comment: @Vignesh when we r giving anMoveRowAtIndexPath to YES we have a three line indicator in the right.i want that fuctionality there it self.but i dont wanted to show that button there.its my need

Comment: did you try adding this one? cell.showsReorderControl = NO;

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in your cell subclass using the below method. I don't think it will work as-is , you need to amend it. But this should be your lead.

```
- (void)willTransitionToState:(UITableViewCellStateMask)state {

[super willTransitionToState:state];
//check whether you need it.
if ((state & UITableViewCellStateShowingEditControlMask) == UITableViewCellStateDefaultMask) {

    for (UIView *subview in self.subviews) {
        //check for reorder control. it checks for delete button.
        if ([NSStringFromClass([subview class]) isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellDeleteConfirmationControl"]) {

            subview.hidden = YES;
            subview.alpha = 0.0;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Modify `tableView(_:canMoveRowAt)` and return **false**, this is an `UITableViewDataSource` method.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return false
}
```