# Swipe to delete option in UITableView issues

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to use "swipe to delete" option in my project.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        NSDictionary *userData = [_contactsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSLog(@"delete row %@",userData);
    }
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    return YES;
}
```

I am using this code but it gives following output which I don't want.[image]

I don't want that left side minus sign on cell.
I just want swipe and show delete button.
The same code I have used in my previous project and it works fine (i.e only swipe to show delete button, no minus sign on left side)

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/shouldIndentWhileEditing

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020922/is-there-any-way-to-hide-delete-button-while-editing-uitableview

Comment: You are overriding the correct UITableViewDelegate methods. But are you setting the 'editing' property of your UITableView to `YES` anywhere in your code? If so, that will cause the red minus signs to be visible.

Comment: @hw731 thanks for your reply. It works for me, I have made small mistake

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are overriding the correct delegate methods for 'swipe to delete' functionality. Regarding the minus signs:

Hide minus sign like this:

```
self.yourTableView.editing = NO;
//or simply remove this line of code altogether because this property is NO by default
```

Show minus sign like this:

```
self.yourTableView.editing = YES;
```

Answer (score 3):

First create your table view and set delegate and datasource method to that.

```
 self.contacts=[[UITable alloc]init];
    self.contacts.dataSource=self;
    self.contacts.delegate=self;
    self.contacts.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
    //self.contacts.editing = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:self.contacts];
```

And then Override the Delegate and data source methods, for delete override the following methods.

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        // Return YES if you want the specified item to be editable.
        return YES;
    }

    // Override to support editing the table view.
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
            //add code here for when you hit delete
        }    
    }
```

For minus sign on left side use **self.contacts.editing = YES;** In my case I don't want this minus sign so simply don't use that property or set **self.contacts.editing = NO;**

Thank you  **hw731** for reminding me this property, I have wasted my half day on this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        // Return YES if you want the specified item to be editable.
        return YES;
    }

    // Override to support editing the table view.
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
            //add code here for when you hit delete
        }    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are turning the `tableView.editing` flag on so the rows show up with the minus sign. try searching for `self.tableView.editing = YES;` and make it `NO` or simply comment that line out.