# How to keep both insert and swipe-in deletion for two rows in a UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In my UITableView, there are two rows. I want add edit(insertion) for the first row.

For second row, I want swipe to delete action(I don't want the red minus button). But I couldn't keep both of these together.
can you please help me? My codes are given below:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.tableView.editing = YES;
}
 - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
     // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
     return YES;
 }

 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
     if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
         // Delete the row from the data source


     }
     else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
         // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
     }
 }

- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            return UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert;
     }   

    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;

}
```

Comment: Consider adding UISwipeGestureRecognizer to the contentView of the cell. It might solve your problems. That way, you can keep your editing style for just the first row, and have the swipe-to-delete for other rows.

Comment: but for that, i have to customise the delete action. right?

Comment: The swipegesturerecognizer works like a button. It will call a function, in which you can perform the deletion of the particular cell. If you would like, I could give you some code that might help.

Comment: thanks it's a good idea. but if it possible appear the delete button like the built-in delete action, it will be better

Comment: First things first, change: return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone; to: return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete; check if that works. Also, you have to implement a delete code.

Comment: done. but the delete button not appearing

Answer (score 0):

I think if you remove

```
self.tableView.editing = YES;
```

than your problem is solved. 
I am not quite sure about that but try that. and tell me you get result.

Comment: no. when i remove the line, addition symbol also disappearing

Comment: I think this might help you for not showing red minus button. here is the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18211736/swipe-to-delete-option-in-uitableview-issues)

Comment: thanks. it works perfect when there was only a delete cell. but i need one insert cell also. so when i set editing 'NO',insertion also set to 'NO'