# swipe is not working on uitableview's cell in ios sdk

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have implemented the customtableview cell with the xib and used in the tableview. below is the code for cellforrowatindexpath

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *CellIdentifier=@"Cell Identifier";

    CustomInboxCell_Iphone *cell=(CustomInboxCell_Iphone *)[_tblView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if(cell==nil)
    {
        if([appDelegate isIphone4]||[appDelegate isIphone5])
            cell=[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomInboxCell_Iphone" owner:self options:nil]objectAtIndex:0];
        else
            cell=[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomInboxCell_Ipad" owner:self options:nil]objectAtIndex:0];


        [cell.btnCheck addTarget:self action:@selector(btnCheckClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }

    cell.btnCheck.tag=indexPath.row;

    cell.lblMain.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",[[_arrList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"first_name"],[[_arrList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"last_name"]];

    if([appDelegate isIpad])
    {
        cell.lblMain.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:25.0f];
    }

    _tblView.separatorColor=[UIColor grayColor];

    cell.lblDesc.text=[[_arrList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"subject"];

    cell.lblTime.text=[[_arrList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"send_date_from"];

    cell.btnCheck.selected=NO;

    if([_dictSelect count]>0)
    {
        NSNumber *temp=[_dictSelect valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row]];


        if(indexPath.row==[temp intValue] && temp!=nil)
            cell.btnCheck.selected=YES;
        else
            cell.btnCheck.selected=NO;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

and also used

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];

         [_dictSelect setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row]];

        [self btnDeleteClicked:nil];
    }
}
```

but still i am not able to swipe, mean when i touch the cell it's selected and then i move my finger a little bit then it get's off & then swipe doesn't work, rarely the swipe work.

So please is there any suggestion/solution to this issue.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: what is the frame for buttoncheck? hide that button and try it maybe that button create issue.

Comment: is your table editable ??????  means you write tableview.editable=YES;

Comment: @i-Maddy i haven't make the button check frame too large

Comment: @ParvendraSingh no my table is not editable

Comment: then make it bro tableview.Editable=YES;...

Comment: then am i able to use swipe to delete option?

Comment: yes do it and check it @JitenParmar

Comment: @parvendraSingh but it displays on all the rows i want i one row at a time when i swipe and don't want to show the red minus icon too...

Comment: @JitenParmar use my code

Answer (score 0):

Use this and modify it according you ....

Here _chat is an array

```
  -(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
       // Return YES if you want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
   }

// Override to support editing the table view.
 -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
       [_chats removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
       [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
   }    
}
```

Comment: your code is right but i am not able to swipe it mean the main swipe will get functioned when we press the row and swipe, but i am not able to swipe the row that's the problem....

Comment: Yup @Pravendra Singh, i am able to touch the row but not able to swipe, if i click on that row i am calling the detail view that's working but not able to swipe on that cell....

Comment: i have written bro but not able to swipe, please provide if you have any another alternate solution.

Comment: i try  for finding some solution

Comment: wait i got solution for you bro @JitenParmar

Comment: once look at this ....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18211736/swipe-to-delete-option-in-uitableview-issues

Comment: i know you were point to self.tableview.editing=YES to make it NO, i have already done that... but at somewhat the swipe works in simulator but not in device, the reason is that the cell are not selected proper with swiping are you getting my point?

Comment: somewhat nice working in simulator but not working in device because the cell is not going to be selected and swipped.. mean if i select the row and swipe the row became unselected... r u getting?