# moveRowAtIndexPath without Delete button

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I need a help in `UITableview` specifically `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath`.

In this if i set `[tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];` Then table contains both delete and moveCell feature. But i need only the moveCell feature. I don't want the delete category.

Like this,

[image: Tableview cell without delete button while Editing]

Is there any way to do this?
Helpers are appreciated.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020922/is-there-any-way-to-hide-delete-button-while-editing-uitableview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use this method so the cell has has no editing control:

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
}
```

in order not to allow indentation background of the specified row:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableview shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return NO;
}
```

and this so the rows can move:

```
-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath          {
    return YES;
 }
```