# Hide (-) delete on moveRowAtIndexPath in Swift 2

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift2

I want to hide the (-) delete option on the `moveRowAtIndexPath` for my `UITableView` on edit.  I saw this could be done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22763287/moverowatindexpath-without-delete-button), but that was not in Swift 2.  I can't find a `return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone` for Swift 2.  Has anyone been able to figure this out? Any help would be great. I could not find anything in the Apple Developer Guide either. Thank you.

Update:
I tried to put `return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.None` in my `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {` section and it would not allow for that. It came up with an error `Unexpected non-void return value in voice function`.

Second Update:
Used the following and it worked for also disabling the indent:

```
// Allow only movement of cells not delete when 'edit' is pressed

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {

    return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.None

}

// Don't indent when there is an edit happening (movement)

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {

    return false

}
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: try `return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.None`

Comment: See my edited answer.  Didn't work.

Comment: You are using the wrong delegate method. You are using `tableView: commitEditingStyle: forRowAtIndexPath:` method instead of `tableView: editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in swift 2 (tested xcode 7.1):

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {
    return .None;
}
```

Comment: That worked!  Is there a way to still implement a swipe left to delete as the only way to delete?

Comment: @ChallengerGuy i think this will be useful:

        `override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

}`

with this method your cells will display delete button on swipe, you can add your custom logic to delete cell/ model you have implemented, hope it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 3.0 correct answer is:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool
{
    return false
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {
    return .none
}
```