# Is it possible to remove the rounded deletion indicator when editing a table view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a table view with edit button, and i add the functionality to the table view to reorder cells using the delegate method moverowatindexpath: toindexpath.

But when i tap the edit button it looks like this:

[image]

And i want this edit button to use only for reordering.

So can i remove the rounded deletion button when i use the edit button, and only when i swipe i will have the deletion button like this?

[image]

I already have the swipe to delete functionality, the only thing i need is that i wNt to remove the deletion functionality when i  tap the edit button, and i should rename the edit button to "reorder" :)

Thanks!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any way to hide "-" (Delete) button while editing UITableView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020922/is-there-any-way-to-hide-delete-button-while-editing-uitableview)

Answer (score 0):

Set these delegate methods:

```
-(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   return YES;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   return YES;
 }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: hey buddy, thanks for the help. two problems, the first is that the ells still goes to the right when i tap the edit button and there is a ui conflict between the text of the cell and the reordering indicator (like in my first image), secode, the swipe to delete function is gone :/

Comment: @nickshmick [This example] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020922/is-there-any-way-to-hide-delete-button-while-editing-uitableview) helped me. I did it too. If something is wrong with UI, try adding constraints.