# How to enable move but disable delete for some row in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

Some rows in my UITableView needs to delete and move in edit mode, but some just move. 
In this method I can enable or disable editing for some rows

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool{
            return true
    }
```

But how to disable delete for some rows with enabled move?

Answer (score 5):

Return `.None` for `editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {
     return .None
}
```

A more complete answer that displays how to remove indentions is here -> [Is there any way to hide "-" (Delete) button while editing UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020922/is-there-any-way-to-hide-delete-button-while-editing-uitableview)