# Is it possible to remove the 'Edit' and '+' buttons on an iOS Master-Detail View?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, ios6

Currently, my iOS (6) application uses the Master-Detail view template, with some list elements being pre-populated. Users currently have the option to 'Edit' and add to ('+') the list. Is there a way of removing these buttons, to prevent the original list being changed?

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987452/how-do-i-disable-the-delete-operation-for-certain-row-in-a-uitableview

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes there is an easy way.

Find this code in `MasterViewController.m` and remove these lines `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;`, `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(insertNewObject:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is just what I was looking for. Sorry I don't have enough rep to up vote your answer yet.

Comment: Haha its fine. Happy Coding :)